# Substitution Loop from regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am stripping out some characters like bulletpoints we don't want from text files, and this regex has been working for many years.

```
$content =~ s/[\xA0\x80\x93\xE2]//g
```

However, we have a very large string from a file now (1.3Gig) that it's breaking on with the following error...

```
Substitution loop
```

The regex looks ok, and from reading on the error and other people who have had the same problem, it looks like there may be some hardcoded internal substitution limit ?

I am using Perl version 5.14.2

If it's just down to a hardcoded limit, is there any way around that, or a still efficient way to achieve the same that wouldn't hit this limit?

Comment: So, `$content` is 1.3G of 'raw' data? It's probably quite a bit bigger in memory.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. I'm not sure exactly how much the string is in memory yet. I know the process uses 6.8Gig, but there are some other datastructures in there, so would probably be a Gig or so less at least. Server has 16Gig mem and has some free.

Comment: I'm not sure why your substitute is failing, but I'd be quite wary generally of 'slurping' such a large quantity straight into memory, just for efficiency reasons.

Comment: Yes, I agree, we do have a solution in another system where we don't load the whole lot into memory to avoid memory issues, but as this is only one file and doesn't cause any problems other than that error, I was wondering whether there is some workarounds without changing too much.

Comment: Here is an explanation and hints: [www.nntp.perl.org](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2014/10/msg221751.html). (see bottom of message) Basicly, number is hardcoded and split your string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that @cbmckay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using it at once in the file? Can you give a try using this approach:

1. Read the file line by line using `while` loop
2. Use regex at one line at a time
3. Write the formatted text to a new file

Please note that I'm using this approach for text file of size around 5GB. My system has just 4GB RAM, and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

This error is obtained when the number of iterations of the substitutions is larger than the number of characters in the string. This should never happen. I suspect the use of a signed 32-bit comparison when an unsigned comparison should be used. This may have been fixed in newer versions of Perl?

For that particular pattern, you could break the string into smaller ones, or you could use a faster C function to do the work:

```
use Inline C => <<'__EOS__';

   /* Limitation: Assumes all characters of the string are in 00..FF */    
   void clean(SV* sv) {
      dXSARGS;

      /* Need to use a "force" call when changing the buffer. */
      STRLEN src_len;
      char* src = SvPVbyte_force(sv, src_len);

      STRLEN dst_len;
      char* dst = src;
      char* orig_dst = dst;

      while (src_len--) {
         switch ((unsigned char)*src) {
            case 0x80:
            case 0x93:
            case 0xA0:
            case 0xE2:
               ++src;
               break;

            default:
               *(dst++) = *(src++);
         }
      }

      dst_len = dst - orig_dst;
      if (dst_len < SvLEN(sv))
         *dst = '\0';

      SvCUR_set(sv, dst_len);
      SvSETMAGIC(sv);
      XSRETURN_EMPTY;
  }

__EOS__

clean($content);
```